# error trying to build/make from source

Tags: command-line, make, gcc, c++

I'm trying to build opendingux from github repo/source. https://github.com/OpenDingux/buildroot

OpenDingux is an embedded Linux distribution focused on (retro) gaming.

I cloned the repo and then ran the commands below.

```
cd ./buildroot;
export CONFIG='gcw0'; bash ./rebuild.sh;
```

The output from the above command was pretty much a wall of text, too long to post in this question as it is 22301 lines long.  The full output is available here https://paste.ee/p/UInYW

I have snipped the error I am getting however below.

```
/bin/bash: line 2: 186552 Killed                  build/genautomata ../../gcc/common.md ../../gcc/config/mips/mips.md insn-conditions.md > tmp-automata.c
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2459: s-automata] Error 137
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
rm gcc.pod
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4415: all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:270: /home/vagrant/buildroot/output/gcw0/build/host-gcc-initial-11.1.0/.stamp_built] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/bin/bash: line 2: 186552 Killed                  build/genautomata ../../gcc/common.md ../../gcc/config/mips/mips.md insn-conditions.md > tmp-automata.c
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2459: s-automata] Error 137
```

means that bash exited with exit code 137 (128 + 9), [which means the process was killed with signal 9, `SIGKILL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html). The most common cause for that on Linux systems (apart from bugs) is when the system runs out of memory and the OOM killer kills a process. So it’s likely that `genautomata` is using too much memory and is being killed.

This should show up in the kernel logs, which you can see with `dmesg`.